# register adwords conversion using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-ads-api

I have seen a few questions asked on here about tracking conversions on Adwords with jQuery.  However, there doesn't seem to be a definitive answer.

I'm trying to register a conversion using the following code after an ajax form has been submitted.  It seems to return a 1x1 image when I look at Firebug network tools, but the conversion hasn't registered yet in my account.  But I am told it can take up to 24 hours.

Will this work?

```
$('<img height="1" width="1" style="border-style:none;" alt="" src="//www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion/xxxx/?label=xxxx&amp;guid=ON&amp;script=0"/>').appendTo('body');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the image loaded (and the code matches the tag they provided) then I'd fully expect it to register but it isnt instanteneous (although IME 24 hrs is Google underpromising to over-deliver).

Its worth just pointing out that legally you need to be careful with this approach as you are in danger of placing a cookie on a user's browser without all the privacy policy compliance stuff. I'm no legal expert (and even if I was, its way outside the scope of a SO answer ;-) ) but just flag it for you to consider...